# What is this `deriving newtype` syntax?

Tags: haskell, deriving, derivingvia

From a blog post I read

```
-- | Newtype for disabling logging
newtype NoLoggingT m a
  = NoLoggingT { runNoLoggingT :: m a }
  deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
  deriving (MonadTrans) via IdentityT

instance Monad m => MonadLog (NoLoggingT m) where logLn _ _ = pure ()
```

What is thas `deriving newtype` syntax?
Which extension is it and what does it do?
Please provide a link to its documentation in the anwser.

Comment: It is helpful to understand `DerivingVia` as a "Generalized `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`": `deriving newtype (F, A, M)` can be replaced with `deriving (F, A, M) via m`. I do not recommend it in practice (always use `deriving newtype` when you are deriving via the underlying representation of a `newtype`) but nevertheless good to understand it as a special case of another feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It lets GHC use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` strategy to derive instances. You need to enable [`DerivingStrategies`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html#extension-DerivingStrategies) extension.